# Galaxy s4 GTI9500 android version to update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'm having this phone for almost two years,
Currently running version 4.2.2 Jelly Bean, frankly don't have any known problems or bugs..
I think of upgrading to some of the `Kitkat` versions, as I know lollipop is still not stable.

My questions are:
1. Currently my phone give me the opportunity to update through FOTA to 4.3, which I've heard is a total catastrophe.
If I do this and than upgrade to 4.4 Kitkat do I collects some bugs on the way from 4.3?

2. Is it possible to upgrade via FOTA from `4.2.2` directly to `4.4`?
3. Where can I find the new bugs\problems that I will probably have after upgrading from `4.2.2` to `4.4` `KitKat`, as I am more than fine with the current behavior of my current `4.2.2` version.
4. Same question as 3 but this time about new features that I will have.
5. Is it recommended to backup all phone content before firmware update?
   What is the chance that my phone will turn into a brick after a firmware
   update or will loose information?

Comment: If the update is official, the chance of bricking the phone is marginal.

Answer (score 0):

I have an S4 on Verizon. I haven't had any issues since the update to Lollipop or before that with Kit-Kat. However the Lollipop update took up a lot of space on my phone which was a pain.
If I were you I'd go straight to Lollipop which, if I understand correctly what FOTA means, is FOTA capable. You shouldn't have any issues from the 4.3 'catastrophe' as you put it. I will warn you though, lollipop changes the look of a lot of things that do take some getting used to. But I've had it for over a month now and I like it same or better than before. I get much better battery life with Battery Save Mode, just don't use it all the time or it becomes ineffective.